# Close all local instances of Realm

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm

I have a problem, with close instance of Realm. I use ThreadPoolExecutor for multithreading and each thread use own Realm instance. I call Realm.getDefaultInstance() before each opetation with Realm. And every time when I appeal to Realm I fetching old data, because every time I call Realm from different threads.

I looked to sources of Realm and saw 33 local references of Realm. When I call Realm.getDefaultInstance().close() and then check that object is closed I get false. But now I have 32 references. How I can to close all instances of Realm, that reset memory cache and fetch actual data?

Comment: *I call Realm.getDefaultInstance() before each operation* why? You should probably do this just one time per thread. *When I call Realm.getDefaultInstance().close() and then check that object is closed I get false.* that does not close the "current" realm. You should really read the documentation to understand how to manage the realm lifecycle

Comment: Because every Realm instance that you obtained with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` must be paired with a `realm.close()`, read https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Comment: Ok, but I check hashcode for Realm object that used in one thread, every instance got after Realm.getDefaultInstance() have same hashcode. Why Realm return new local instance after getDefaultInstance()  and not global instance for current thread?

I need close every local instance of Realm?
I can somehow close all local instances?

Comment: To easily allow opening Realms in `onCreate()` and closing them in `onDestroy()` for the UI thread, of course. If you closed **any** activity and every Realm on the UI thread were invalidated, that'd be pretty bad, wouldn't you say? :p

Comment: `I need close every local instance of Realm?` that's generally easy because every background thread should have only 1 local instance, obtained with `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { ... }` wrapping the lifetime of the thread, and passed to methods as argument.

Comment: Ah, keeping track of your own "thread-local instances" works too.

Comment: If you have found a solution, do post it as an answer!

Comment: I have more complexy structure, every method that worked with Realm call Realm.getDefaultInstance() and when I checked count local references with Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(...) i got 33 references, but only 3 global instances, because my thread pool have 3 threads, that is correct(count global instances).

Comment: @TimCastelijns ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem writed `RealmManager`, instaed `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`, I use `RealmManager.getInstance()`. More not necessary call `realm.close()` after each `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`

RealmManager:

```
import android.util.LongSparseArray;

import io.realm.Realm;

public class RealmManager {
    private volatile static LongSparseArray<Realm> THREAD_INSTANCES = new LongSparseArray<>();

    public static Realm getInstance() {
        final long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

        if (THREAD_INSTANCES.indexOfKey(threadId) >= 0) {
            Realm instance = THREAD_INSTANCES.get(threadId);

            if (instance == null || instance.isClosed()) {
                instance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                THREAD_INSTANCES.put(threadId, instance);
            }

            return instance;
        } else {
            Realm instance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            THREAD_INSTANCES.put(threadId, instance);

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public static void closeInstance() {
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

        if (THREAD_INSTANCES.indexOfKey(threadId) >= 0) {
            Realm instance = THREAD_INSTANCES.get(threadId);

            if (instance == null || instance.isClosed()) {
                THREAD_INSTANCES.remove(threadId);
            } else {
                instance.close();
                instance = null;

                THREAD_INSTANCES.remove(threadId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My JobExecutor:

```
public class JobExecutor implements Executor {
    private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
    private final java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService mThreadPoolExecutor;
    private final DiskDataSource mDiskDataSource;

    public JobExecutor(DiskDataSource diskDataSource) {
        mDiskDataSource = diskDataSource;
        mThreadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CORE_POOL_SIZE, new JobThreadFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
        mThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new RealmRunnable(mDiskDataSource, runnable));
    }

    private static class JobThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        private static final String THREAD_NAME = "android_";
        private int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
            return new Thread(runnable, THREAD_NAME + counter++);
        }
    }
}
```

RealmRunnable:

```
public class RealmRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Runnable mOrigRunnable;
    private DiskDataSource mDiskDataSource;

    public RealmRunnable(DiskDataSource diskDataSource, Runnable origRunnable) {
        mDiskDataSource = diskDataSource;
        mOrigRunnable = origRunnable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mOrigRunnable.run();
        } finally {
            mDiskDataSource.closeDatabaseInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `DiskDataSource` I use `RealmManager`